# Bootstrap - Pull Icon to Left of Text

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In Bootstrap 3, I want to have an icon centered to the left of an H6 and some text.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
         <div class="pull-left"><i class="fa fa-life-ring fa-3x"></i></div>
         <div class="pull-right">
         <h6>Unlimited Support</h6>
         We're here to help! Just ask away...
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It looks like this right now (icon is above the text, rather than on the left):

[image: screenshot1]

How do I get it to format correctly?

This code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
         <div class="pull-right">
             <h6><i class="fa fa-life-ring fa-3x"></i> Unlimited Support</h6>
             We're here to help! Just ask away...
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Displays like this:

[image: screenshot2]

But, I want to put the icon beside both lines of text (have the "We're here..." move to the right/not wrap underneath.

Comment: Are you sure "Unlimited Support" is an h6? Look too big...

Answer (score 5):

you can try this

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sunnypmody/h3c9F/)

```
<div class="media">
  <a class="pull-left" href="#">
    <img class="media-object" src="..." alt="...">
  </a>
  <div class="media-body">
    <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

If it's Bootstrap you could do something like this:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-2">
    <i class="fa fa-life-ring fa-3x"></i>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-10">
     <h6>Unlimited Support</h6>
     We're here to help! Just ask away...
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works great and there is no need to add extra styles, also works with Bootstrap 4

Comment: Note that the grid columns in a row should add up to 12. More than that, columns will stack no matter the viewport.

Comment: That looks good. Possibly remove the inner distance with the class "p-0".

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
         <div class="pull-right">
             <h6><i class="fa fa-life-ring fa-3x"></i> Unlimited Support</h6>
             We're here to help! Just ask away...
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can try this (if you do not want your text pulled to the right).

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
         <h6><i class="fa fa-life-ring fa-3x"></i> Unlimited Support</h6>
         We're here to help! Just ask away...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I gave it a try -- it's closer. See my edit to the original message (at the end).

Answer (score 0):

you can add put the text "We're here to help!..." in a span and give it some padding or margin on the left.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-8">
     <div class="pull-right">
         <h6><i class="fa fa-life-ring fa-3x"></i> Unlimited Support</h6>
         <span class="text-on-the-right">We're here to help! Just ask away...</span>
     </div>
</div>
</div>
```

the CSS for the span class:
    .text-on-the-right
    {
        margin-left:10px/* or the desired the width */
    }

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it should be simple enough, but you need to bash your elements around with some forced margins... here goes:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 custom">
  <i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-3x pull-left"></i>
  <div class="text">
    <h6 class="custom-margin">Unlimited Support</h6>
      We're here to help! Just ask away...
```

CSS:

```
.text{margin-left: 60px;overflow: hidden;}
.custom-margin{margin-top:4px;margin-bottom:4px}
```

**EXAMPLE: http://www.bootply.com/qvjfInH7yQ**

ps - your code shows an h6 for "Unlimited Support" but your example image looks like it's something else. I've used h6 as starting point, but if it's something else, you'll need some more <s>bashing</s> precise tweaking of margins to get it into the right exact placement.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach would be an alternative to the Bootstrap Grid:

```
<div>
    <img class=position-absolute src="ICONNAME.svg" alt="ICON-ALT" width="40" height="40">
    <div class=pl-3>
    text right
    </div>
</div>
```

[Manual Bootstrap Spacing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/)